# Ends as fixpoints, a different story?

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\def\C{\mathcal{C}}$Let $F: \C^\text{op} \times \C \to \C$ be a bifunctor on a category such that $\int_CF$ exists.

One can evaluate $F$ on its end, i.e. look at the object $F(\int_CF,\int_CF)$.

> What can be said about this object? Is it always the case that $F(\int_CF,\int_CF)\cong\int_CF$, i.e. that $\int_CF$ is a solution for the "fixpoint equation" $F(T,T)\cong T$?

I have only thought very superficially about this question (for the hom-functors of a few monoidal categories, the end of $F$ is a fixpoint), and since it has absolutely no further motivation, I'll leave it as a toy for whoever is interested.

Comment: Say, pick an element $A\ne1$ of a Heyting algebra and let $F(X,Y)=X\to A$. Then the end is $1$ since $F(A,A)=1$. But $F(1,1)=A$.

Comment: Thanks, this also answers to the question "how far the two can be". I wonder if there are examples where F is not mute in one variable

Comment: Say, $((A\to Y)\to X)\to A$

Comment: For a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra over a field, the end of $F(X, Y) = X \otimes Y^*$ exists in the category of finite-dimensional $H$-modules and is isomorphic to the adjoint representation. So in this case, $\dim F(\int_C F, \int_C F) = (\dim H)^2$.